# Numerical Integration on Matlab

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I am modeling a solenoid in Matlab. I am in the process of evaluating the value of inductance L of the solenoid at each step of the plunger movement.

Using the force-stroke characteristic data, I have evaluated the value of dL/dx at each step, where x represents plunger's position.

Can you please tell me how I can integrate dL/dx, so that I get each value of L as a function of x.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already approximated the slopes (dL/dx) you could simply use a `for` loop to deploy an Euler or Runge-Kutta (RK) method. If you would rather avoid having to script those yourself, I refer you to the function `ode45`. It is a general ODE solver based on the "optimal Runge-Kutta" method meant for non-stiff problems.

Here's a link to the MATLAB documentation on `ode45`:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html